# Перегрузка метода (аргументы или параметры)?

Tags: java

Читаю книгу и не могу понять: 
Перегрузка метода - это не что иное, как наличие нескольких методов с одним именем, но разными наборами аргументов. В процессе перегрузки методов полиморфизм не задействуется.
Перегрузка позволяет создавать несколько версий одного метода с разным списком аргументов, делая их более удобными для вызова.

Разве не должно быть вот так: 
Перегрузка метода - это не что иное, как наличие нескольких методов с одним именем, но разными наборами **параметров**. В процессе перегрузки методов полиморфизм не задействуется.
Перегрузка позволяет создавать несколько версий одного метода с разным списком **параметров**, делая их более удобными для вызова.

Comment: Да, должно быть вот так (со словом "параметров").

Answer (score 0):

Вы абсолютно правы, параметры это то, что принимает метод, аргумент - это то, что туда передается.